# How to copy multiple rows, change column value and insert in same table

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have a table `T` that has columns `T_Id`, `A`, and `B`. I want to find all rows that have a specific `A` value, increment the `T_Id` value and insert the new row into `T` with a new `A` value.

#### For Example:

If I have the following table

```
| T_Id | A   | B      |
|------|-----|--------|
| 1    | ABC | Value1 |
| 2    | ABC | Value2 |
| 3    | BCD | Value3 |
```

I would like the resulting table to look something like this:

```
| T_Id | A   | B      |
|------|-----|--------|
| 1    | ABC | Value1 |
| 2    | ABC | Value2 |
| 3    | BCD | Value3 |
| 4    | CDE | Value1 |
| 5    | CDE | Value2 |
```

The current script I have attempting to do this is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [T]([T_Id],[A],[B])
SELECT Count(*)+1,'CDE',[B]
FROM [T]
WHERE [A] = 'ABC'
```

However, I receive this error upon executing `Column 'T.B' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`
I believe this is not working as there are multiple records that will be returned from the `SELECT` statement.

Any suggestions on how to remedy this situation would be appreciated!

Comment: What would be your expected output if, for example, you wanted to expand from 3 to 10 rows?  And why not just make `T_Id` an auto increment column?

Comment: Anytime you try to roll your own incrementing value like this it is going to fail. There are just too many pitfalls do doing this manually. That is the advantage of using identity, they already worked out all the kinks.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [T]([T_Id],[A],[B])
SELECT (SELECT MAX(T_Id) FROM T) + 1,'CDE',[B]
  FROM [T]
 WHERE [A] = 'ABC'
 ORDER BY T_Id ASC
```

This should work. You cant use the aggregation function count if you have columns that are not in the group by cause.

Comment: But how can you guarantee the order in which the old selected records will be inserted?  I think your current code might result in `(4, CDE, Value2)` and `(5, CDE, Value1)` being inserted.

Comment: Agree with @TimBiegeleisen. You would have to put an order by on the final select statement here to ensure the order is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to remedy this situation would be appreciated!

I suggest you make `T_id` an IDENTITY column.   Then you don't have to worry about it in the insert, and you can just do the INSERT..SELECT you have already written, without the `T_id` reference.

Comment: But what about inserting the value strings in numerical order?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen re-reading the question, and I don't see any need to insert the value strings in numerical order.   I don't understand your question.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying, and I think you are assuming a requirement based on the sample output that isn't necessarily required.  That requirement isn't stated in the first paragraph, and in introducing the sample output, OP says "something like this:" so I don't think the exact order of column B is necessarily important.